# access JComponents into another java non GUI class

Tags: java, swing

How can I access any JComponent (e.i. JTextField) of a class in another non GUI class?  I want to access them so that I can implement all my functions in a non GUI class and then call those functions in the GUI listener. 
For example:

```
public class New_Client {
     private JFrame frmNewClient;
     private JTextField txt_FirstName,txt_LastName,txt_Address,txt_Phone;
     private JButton submit;
     public New_Client() {
         //initializing frame and other components
          ...
        txt_FirstName = new JTextField();
        txt_FirstName.setBounds(350,220,300,80);
        frmNewClient.getContentPane().add(txt_FirstName);

        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.setSize(115,55);
        submit.setLocation(800,420);
        frmNewClient.getContentPane().add(submit);

        submit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            ReceptionsitClass.insertRecords();
        }
    });
}
```

}

And the other  class is as follows:

```
public class Person {

private int id;
private String firstName, lastName, address, phone;

public Person(int ID, String fName, String lName, String addr, String tel){
    this.id = ID;
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
    this.address = addr;
    this.phone = tel;
}

public int getID(){
    return this.id;
}
```

}

And another class is ReceptionistClass which implements the insert function:

```
public class ReceptionistClass {

public void InsertRecord() {

    Connection.getDBConnection().Connect();
    //String FirstName = txt_FirstName.getText(); 
    // How can I access txt_FirstName.getText() so that I can pass that value to the query and store it...
   ...
  // Person p = New Person(ID, FirstName,LastName, Adress, Phone);
}
```

}

Comment: Did you write an `ActionListener` for the text field?

Comment: "*How can I achieve this?*" Write an `ActionListrner` for the text field. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Comment: "*the listener in the GUI New_Client class*" What listener? I don't see any. You should [edit] your question with the relevant code and clear instructions. Include what packages the classes are in.

Comment: [`Action`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) is intended for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues and some ways to make it right.
Simplest way (not recommended) make field static and public:

```
  public static JTextField txt_FirstName,txt_LastName,txt_Address,txt_Phone;
```

than you can access it in any class like this

```
String FirstName = New_Client.txt_FirstName.getText();
```

A little better way is make it not static but then you have to have instance of this New_Client in your classes and use it like this:

```
    New_Client new_client=null; // initialize it before use
//...
    String FirstName = new_client.txt_FirstName.getText();
```

There are other more appropriate ways to this in right way. I would recommend [MVC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html) Model-View-Controller. You should separate your data from your view and controls. Maybe it looks like overkill for simple SWING application but that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this backwards.

When you build a GUI, you should use the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  Not only do you separate your concerns into a model, a view, and one or more controllers, you develop in this order.  First, you create the model, then the view, and finally the controller(s).

So, let's take a look at your model. I've included all of the getters and the setters.

```
public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String firstName, lastName, address, phone;

    public Person(int ID, String fName, String lName, String addr,
            String tel) {
        this.id = ID;
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
        this.address = addr;
        this.phone = tel;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

}
```

Next, you have to pass the model to the view.  Here's a mostly corrected version of your view.

```
public class NewClient {
    private JFrame frmNewClient;
    private JTextField txt_FirstName, txt_LastName, txt_Address, txt_Phone;
    private JButton submit;

    public NewClient() {
        final Person person = new Person(100, "John", "Smith", "", "");

        // initializing frame and other components

        frmNewClient = new JFrame("New Client");
        frmNewClient.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        txt_FirstName = new JTextField();
        txt_FirstName.setText(person.getFirstName());
        panel.add(txt_FirstName);

        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                person.setFirstName(txt_FirstName.getText().trim());
                ReceptionistClass rc = new ReceptionistClass();
                rc.insertRecord(person);
            }
        });
        panel.add(submit);

        frmNewClient.add(panel);
        frmNewClient.pack();
        frmNewClient.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And finally, you have your controller class writing your Person to the database.

```
public class ReceptionistClass {

    public void insertRecord(Person person) {

        Connection.getDBConnection().Connect();
        // You don't care about the view here.
        // All you care about is the Person instance.
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you to organize your code so that you can focus on one small piece at a time.

Comment: Why are you creating an instance of Person class and passing the arguments and then setting the text to jTextField?

Comment: @Afrim: Because this is a simple example.  Your view will have to have separate JPanels for adding a person, changing a person, and deleting a person.  Your Person instances are the model, and the code to read from and write to the database will be part of the controller.